# How to display image inside another image in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am trying to display an image in background and on top of that another image will be displayed.How can I do this in LWC?

Answer (score 2):

You'd do it just as you would in normal HTML:

```
<img src="image1" style="background-image: url(image2)" />
```

Where image1 and image2 are URLs to images stored in static resources or elsewhere.

If the image doesn't have transparency, though, you'll find the background may not show up. You would want a wrapper element for the background:

```
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center style="background-image: url(image2)">
  <img src="image1" />
</div>
```

Comment: You could also use two img tags. One with `position:absolute`. Put them both in a div with `position:relative`.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Thanks but  the syntax is not working in lwc. Could you pls check the below code bz customerLogo is not coming in UI but backGroundPic is coming :  <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="background-image: url({customerLogo})">
       <img src={backGroundPic} />
    </div>

Comment: @stackasaur, when i am using those two then nothing is coming in UI other than 2 images.